# What am I forgetting about OnClickListener?

Tags: android

I'm knocking together what amounts to an RSS reader in Android, and I'm having a problem with onClickListener.

The following code run fine outside of the onClickListener, but as soon as I move it inside the class it

```
        topNewsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newsTop);

    topNewsbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent itemintent = new Intent(that,RSSReader.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("FeedURL", "http://english.aljazeera.net/Services/Rss/?PostingId=2007731105943979989");
            itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);
            startActivity(itemintent);
        }


    });
```

N.B. that is defined in the Activity as a Context and within onCreate assigned as that = this

On execution the app crashed on start-up with the following stack trace (nothing in LogCat)

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception java.lang.RuntimeException))    
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, android.content.Intent) line: 2663  
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, android.content.Intent) line: 2679   
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, android.content.Intent) line: 125 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) line: 2033   
    android.app.ActivityThread$H(android.os.Handler).dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) line: 99   
    android.os.Looper.loop() line: 123  
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) line: 4627  
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Class, java.lang.Class[], java.lang.Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object...) line: 521    
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) line: 626   
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(java.lang.String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I have another onClickListener that also crashes with the same sort of stack trace and that looks like

```
        watchLivebtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Live);
    watchLivebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.watchnowElement);

            String HTML = "Just some HTML I want to display";
            browser.loadData(HTML, "text/html", "UTF-8");

            setContentView(R.layout.watchnow);

        }
    });
```

So clearly I'm doing something that wrong with the setOnClickListener, but what?

Thanks.

**update**

I resisted puting the whole class in because it's so long, as the two people who've tryed to help me (Thanks) have pointed out stuff I've don't I'll post the whole thing to help you all help me.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SlidingDrawer;


public class AJE extends Activity {

Button news_slideHandleButton;
SlidingDrawer news_slidingDrawer;


Button topNewsbtn;
Button watchLivebtn;

Context that;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    that = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    news_slideHandleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news_slideHandleButton);
    news_slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.news_SlidingDrawer);


    topNewsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newsTop);

    topNewsbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent itemintent = new Intent(that,RSSReader.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("FeedURL", "http://english.aljazeera.net/Services/Rss/?PostingId=2007731105943979989");
            itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);
            startActivity(itemintent);
        }


    }); 

    watchLivebtn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.Live);
    watchLivebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.watchnowElement);

            String HTML = "<html><body><script src='http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js' type='text/javascript'></script>" +
                          "<script src='/custom/brightcove/aje_bc.js' type='text/javascript'></script>"+
                          "<div style='text-align: left; padding-bottom: 20px;'>" +
                          "<div id='BCplayerArea' style='width: 680px; height: 420px;'><object class='BrightcoveExperience' id='myExperience747084146001' data='http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?&amp;width=680&amp;height=440&amp;flashID=myExperience747084146001&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;playerID=751182905001&amp;playerKey=AQ~~%2CAAAAmtVJIFk~%2CTVGOQ5ZTwJYW4Aj2VxnKEXntSbmcf9ZQ&amp;isVid=true&amp;isUI=true&amp;dynamicStreaming=true&amp;%40videoPlayer=747084146001&amp;autoStart=' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='680' height='440'><param value='always' name='allowScriptAccess'><param value='true' name='allowFullScreen'><param value='false' name='seamlessTabbing'><param value='true' name='swliveconnect'><param value='window' name='wmode'><param value='high' name='quality'><param value='#FFFFFF' name='bgcolor'></object></div>"+
                          "<script type='text/javascript'>// <![CDATA["+
                          "RenderScVideo('747084146001','751182905001',680,440,'BCplayerArea');"+ 
                          "brightcove.createExperiences();    // ]]></script></body></html>';";
            browser.loadData(HTML, "text/html", "UTF-8");

            setContentView(R.layout.watchnow);

        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just thought I'd add (I don't think it's reinvent but...) the first button is within a SlidingDrawer and so hidden on start-up.

Comment: Where did this come from: "Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception java.lang.RuntimeException))"? The debugger?

Comment: @Bert, Yea the Eclipse debugger, their was noting of interest in LogCat just the thread suspended message in the debug tab...

Comment: Another point I'd like to add. It is generally not a good idea to do stuff before up-calling the base class using the `super` keyword. Generally you should first make the up-call and then do whatever you have to do.

Comment: @Scott - Hmm, that's what I thought.  I think the debugger suspended the thread before it had a chance to print the exception.  If so, get the debugger to continue the thread and the thread will print the exception and full stack trace back into logcat.  If I'm right, that stack trace will be a big help.

Comment: @BertF The stack trace will show an `NPE` pointing to the line which tries to access something which is not there yet. See my updated answer.

Comment: Have you tried to comment out the whole code within OnClick? Probably, it's not the problem of ClickListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of an inner class `this` will get you the reference to the class you are currently in and not to the Activity.

Initialize a `Context` object inside of your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method to use it inside of the inner class.

There is another possibility which is not encouraged. I'm only showing you the possibilities and repeat myself that it is not encouraged to use this method as you might leak the entire Activity depending on the code you are passing that context to.

You could get the Activity like this `MyActivity.this`. It would work but don't do it that way as long as you are not 100% sure know that you are not going to leak it.

---

**UPDATE**

Your problem is something else in fact. You are setting the layout after accessing it which won't work. So you have to set the layout using `setContentView()` preferably directly after the up-call to super.

The main problem is you are trying to access views that simply are not there yet which makes the application crash of course.

Comment: Yep, moving `setContentView()` up to it's rightful place fixed it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are importing:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

What's the meaning of `that` in:

```
Intent itemintent = new Intent(that,RSSReader.class);
```

Comment: "Intent itemintent = new Intent(that,RSSReader.class);" Launches a new Activity (RSSReader) and passes some data to it (the URL of the feed) that is a Context that in onCreate is set to this.

Comment: @Scott Herbert: What's the point of setting `that` to `this`. That's very nonstandard, and as seen in this answer, can be very confusing.

Comment: @Falmarri because I need to pass the Context of the activity to the new Intent, as it's being called within a sub class (onClickListener) if I use `this` is passes the Context of the inner class, not the activity. See Octavian Damiean pre-update answer for a better worded answer.

Comment: @Scott Herbert: Then instead of calling it that, you should name it `ctx`, or some other descriptive variable. But also, you don't even need that variable because you can access your activity's `this` pointer by doing `AJE.this`

Comment: @Falmarri, AJE.this is dangerous, it may leak... also I wouldn't call ctx more descriptive, If I wanted to do that I'd call it copyOfMainActivityContext but I didn't...

Comment: @Scott Herbert: There's nothing wrong with `AJE.this`. In fact that's the correct way of doing it. That's the same as saving it in a variable. In fact, the variable is MORE Likely to leak since you now are storing a reference.

Answer (score 0):

As basicly said by Octavian Damiean.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    that = this;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    /*
     if R.id.news_slideHandleButton and R.id.news_SlidingDrawer are on this view 
     it has to be set before try to access elements on it
    */
    setContentView(R.layout.start);

    news_slideHandleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news_slideHandleButton);
    news_slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.news_SlidingDrawer);

    // the listeners go here
}
```